# How to make Vue reactive content update quickly?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with Vue being sluggish on updating reactive content.

I want users to select items from a list. When items are selected they should be marked. For test I am just setting a border around the selected items. The problem is when I have multiple items, I feel that Vue takes very long time to update (react) the class on the selected items.

So I have a simple reactive store which looks as follows:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selections: []
  },
  mutations: {
    set_selections (state, sel) {
      state.selections = sel;
    }
  }
})
```

I pass this store to my component which renders a simple list which will contain many items.

```html
<p v-for="item in items">
    <span v-bind:class="{ 'is-selected': isSelected(item) }" v-on:click="onSelect(item)">
        {{ item.name }}
    </span>
</p>
```

So each item will have a unique id which I add/remove from my Vuex store state, selections:

```js
onSelect: function(item, event){
    let itemId = item._id;
    let sel = this.selections;
    if (sel.indexOf(itemId) !== -1) {
        var index = sel.indexOf(itemId);
        sel.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        sel.push(itemId);
    }
    this.$store.commit("set_selections", sel);
},
```

where,

```js
selections: function() {
    return this.$store.state.selections;
}
```

is a computed property which fetches the current selections.

The method which checks if the item is selected, and thus adds the "is-selected" class to the DOM element, looks as follows:

```js
isSelected: function(item){
    let itemId = item._id;
    let sel = this.selections;
    if (sel.indexOf(itemId) !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
},
```

**Problem**
When I have many items in my list I feel that the reactive content is very sluggish. When I click on an item it takes about 500ms to 1 sec before the item is marked. (Note I have very many item). Am, I perhaps doing something wrong? Since I loop using , `v-for`, I understand that Vue must recalculate the `isSelected` method for every item which might be time consuming.

Ofcourse I could add/remove the class directly on the onClick event but then I loose the whole point of using Vue. How would you deal with this problem?

Comment: This is almost always solved by refactoring your list items into a component so that Vue doesn't have to redraw the entire list.

Comment: But how would you do that? I would still need to loop over each items in order to render them? And if the "isSelected" was calculated in the component instead, it will still call "isSelected" on each item when it is updated.

Comment: Sure, but only the component that changed would need to be redrawn. Not everything in the list. Put together a working example in a fiddle/pen and we can work on refactoring.

Comment: Make sure you add a `key` to the element you're `v-for`ing on. That might fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. So if I do not put each item in a component? Vue actually re-renders the whole list?

Comment: Here you go: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your list updating is slow because iterating over your selection array can be expensive if you're doing this in thousand components/items.

Also as mentioned in the comments `key` binding can improve the speed as well (speed difference not tested).

But in my demo the best result was after creating an selection object and just check the property in `selected`.

And it better to do `selected` check as computed property - it's faster.

For computed property it takes around 200ms to select the item with a list of 1000 items. With a selection method it would take ~450ms - not exactly sure why it is so much slower.

Here is a screenshot of the performance for one selection event 200ms (Tested in Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (64bit) - i5-6200 / 8GB RAM / Win10):
[image: Screenshot 200ms]

At the moment, this is my fastest version. I've also started with 0,5 to 1 sec to display the selection.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/keqh7j00/1).

```js
const listItem = {
 props: ['item'],
 template: `
   <li :class="{ 'is-selected': selected }" @click="$emit('selected', item)">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  `,
  computed: {
   ...Vuex.mapState(['selections']),
    selected () {
     // 200ms time to mark item for click with 1000 list items - clicked Test 326
     return this.selections[this.item.id] !== undefined; // object property check is fast
    }
  },
  methods: {
   selected () {
     // 450ms to mark selection
     //console.log('selected', this.selections, !!this.selections[this.item.id]);
      // slightly slower than computed property
     return this.selections[this.item.id] !== undefined; // object property check is fast
     // array --> slow because another iteration for each component required
     //this.selections.indexOf(this.item) !== -1
    }
  }
};

const list = {
 props: ['items'],
 template: `
   <ul>
     <list-item 
       v-for="item in items" 
        :item="item" 
        @selected="select"
        :key="item.id"></list-item>
   </ul>
  `,
  components: {
   listItem
  },
  methods: {
   select(item) {
     this.$store.commit('set_selection', item)
    }
  }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
    selections: []
  },
  mutations: {
    set_selection (state, item) {
      //state.selections = sel;
      console.log('clicked', item, state.selections[item.id]);
      
      if (state.selections[item.id]) {
       // in object --> remove from selection
       //let  {[item.id]: deleted, ...newState} = state;
        state.selections[item.id] = undefined;
      }
      else {
       // not in object --> add item
       state.selections = {
         ...state.selections,
         [item.id]: item
        }
      }
      // console.log(state.selections, !!state.selections[item.id]);
      
      /*
      --> array approach is slow
      if (state.selections.indexOf(item) === -1) 
      {
       // not in list --> push to list
       state.selections.push(item);
      }
      else {
       // in list --> remove selection
       state.selections.pop(item);
      }*/
    }
  }
})

function createItems(count) {
 let items = [];
  for(let i=0; i< count; i++) {
   items.push({
     id: i,
      name: 'Test ' + i
    });
  }
  return items;
}

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  store,
  data () {
   let items = createItems(1000);
   return {
     items
    };
  },
  components: {
   list
  }
})
```

```css
.is-selected {
   background-color: red;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.3.1/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <list :items="items"></list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I changed the array to a dictionary and then I also had to use `Vue.set(state.selections, item.id, item)` for Vue to react on the change.It's a little bit faster now.

I modified your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9o17yheq/1/

But I dont still understand why it is so slow after selecting about 5 items when it is a dictionary?

Comment: You're welcome. I can't see that it's getting slower after 5 or more selections. (I haven't measured the time but it doesn't seem to be slower). In which browser have you seen that behaviour?

Comment: So here is what really speed things up. Preallocate all keys in the dictionary when starting the component. That makes all the difference. I cant see any lag at all now-

https://jsfiddle.net/9o17yheq/2/

Comment: I have only tested in Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (64 bit)

Comment: Wow, cool. With the pre-allocation it's working perfectly. No delays.